# JPA NativeQuery does not set special mysql field

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

As suggested in the comments it's a Transient field. This makes it not being handled. But I don't want a field in the database since saving position would make it incorrect as soon as someone new makes a score between any of the old scores. Is there a way to fake the field so that JPA will fill the field?

I am using mysql and I am trying to get the row number of ther ordered list I get back.

Making this object a "Hallmaster" object will not set the position field in Hallmaster. If I make it a generic List it will contain the correct information. I assume that JPA does not see the field position in Hallmaster as the same as this "@position:=@position+1 AS position"

```
listHallmastaren = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT  id, @position:=@position+1 AS position, " +
    " e.name, e.score FROM HALLMASTER e, (SELECT @position:=0) t ORDER BY e.score desc", Hallmaster.class).getResultList();
```

Added Hallmaster class

```
public class Hallmaster implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; // still set automatically

    @Transient
    private Long position;
    private String name;
    private Integer score;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Hallmaster() {
        super();

        this.position = 0L;
        this.name = "Nytt";
        this.score = 0;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public long getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }

    public void setPosition(long position) {
        this.position = position;
    }   
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
    public Integer getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    public void setScore(Integer score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

Comment: `position` is `@Transient` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)

Comment: Why can't you use the position within the list you get back?  Storing it in the entity would cause you issues when you issue multiple queries that might have different ordering, as they will all return the same instance, but attempt to set that field differently.

Comment: Because adding a new person with a new score would render the current position order invalid.